# Select subscriptions based on user id

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have these MySQL tables where I want to store user subscriptions:

```
CREATE TABLE subscription (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `error` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `run_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_transaction_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_transactionId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23443556 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO subscription (`id`, `amount`, `created_at`, `currency`, `duration`, `end_at`, `error`, `order_id`, `product`, `run_at`, `start_at`, `status`, `updated_at`, `title`, `parent_transaction_id`, `parent_transactionId`) VALUES 
('122', '3333.00', '2020-10-31 19:41:16.622386', 'USD', '1000', '2020-10-31 19:41:16.622386', 'error message', '122', 'error message', '2020-10-31 19:41:16.622386', '2020-10-31 19:41:16.622386', 'active', '2020-10-31 19:41:16.622386', 'title', '443', '5544');

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `encrypted_password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=153 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `enabled`, `encrypted_password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `role`) VALUES 
('192', 'test@mail.com', '1', '$2a$31$ovShEKleI3Yk2vgjAIF5mO4HkGWXcTSKPMTaj7rFN4KAtlEz0f/ay', 'test', 'test', 'ROLE_CLIENT');

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTENT` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grand_total` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_discount` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `promo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `province` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_total` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=65 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `city`, `CONTENT`, `country`, `created_at`, `email`, `first_name`, `grand_total`, `item_discount`, `last_name`, `status`, `sub_total`, `tax`, `total`, `user_id`) VALUES 
('122', 'city', 'test context', 'USA', '2021-05-25 12:40:23.793779', 'test@email.com', 'first name', '100', '10', 'last name', 'active', '20', '10', '200', '192');
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `city`, `CONTENT`, `country`, `created_at`, `email`, `first_name`, `grand_total`, `item_discount`, `last_name`, `status`, `sub_total`, `tax`, `total`, `user_id`) VALUES 
('124', 'city', 'test context', 'USA', '2021-05-25 12:40:23.793779', 'test@email.com', 'first name', '100', '10', 'last name', 'active', '20', '10', '200', '192');


CREATE TABLE `order_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `discount` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d6ba6/1

I use this SQL query with 2 JOINS to get the subsriptions:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscription
INNER JOIN Orders ON subscription.order_id = Orders.id AND subscription.id = 122
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = users.id AND Orders.user_id = 192
ORDER BY subscription.id;
```

As you can see I use 2 params in order to make 2 JOINS. Is it possible just to send the user id as a param and based from the match `Orders.id AND subscription.id` to get the subscription records that are found?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do you have one parameter or two?  What results do you want?  If you want columns from all three tables -- which the `select *` implies -- then you need all three tables in the query.

Comment: as a result I need the subscription for the user based on user id

Comment: @PeterPensov . . . I would just suggest that you ask a new question, with a clear description of what you want to do, sample data, and desired results.  This question has been answered, so it would be unfair to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query didn't make sense, with ON Clause that links orders and user

So you can achieve the same result, without the user

```
SELECT *
FROM subscription
INNER JOIN Orders ON subscription.order_id = Orders.id AND subscription.id = 122
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = Orders.user_id
ORDER BY subscription.id;
```

btw the user of aliases can help keep more overview

```
SELECT *
FROM subscription s
INNER JOIN Orders o  ON s.order_id = o.id AND s.id = 122
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = o.user_id
ORDER BY s.id;
```

Comment: One more additional question. How I can send date range to the query? I would like to get the most recent subscription query?

Comment: Order By s.`created_at` DESC and LIMIT 1

Comment: how I can specify a date range?

Comment: I get `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND LIMIT 1' at line 5`

Comment: i am unsure whar you are doing see if this helps else make a new fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d6ba6/29